# How can I change the color of one single road on a Mapbox layer that has hundreds of roads?

Tags: mapbox

I have a network of roads displaying on a layer in Mapbox. On `mouseenter` of a given individual road segment, I want to change it's `line-color`. I'm able to successfully change all the roads together as a whole, but how can I target a single road segment and change its color?

I've tried things like this but haven't found much luck targeting an invidual road segment:

```
map.on('mouseenter', 'road-street', (e) => {
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
  let uniqueId = "road-" + String(Date.now());
  e.features[0].layer.id = uniqueId;
  map.setPaintProperty(e.features[0].layer.id, 'line-color', '#0099ff');
});
```

But this generates an `Object Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layers like `road-street` in Mapbox Streets don't contain unique attributes (such as an ID) that would let you easily color them individually. However, they do have unique geometry (with some caveats: the geometry of an individual feature is not necessarily the whole road, or what you expect to find as "the road").

You can do something like this:

1. Create a separate source `selected-road` of type `line`
2. Create a separate layer `selected-road` of type `line`, connected to the source.
3. When the user clicks/hovers, update its geometry like this:

`map.getSource('selected-road').setData(e.features[0].geometry)`